# \bar{\hat{R}} gives 3 errors. WHY?

Tags: symbols, characters

`\bar{\hat{R}}` gives 3 errors: Missing number, treated as zero, and illegal unit of measure and undefined control sequence. WHY?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\bar{\hat{R}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added an example but it makes no errors, please edit it so that it produces the errors that you get, which are presumably because you are using non standard definitions that you have not shown.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! do you insert your math exoresion in math environment. for example like `$\bar{\hat{R}}$`?

Comment: I also got no error...